# How to use the result of combn and a data frame to get a new matrix?

Tags: r

Here is my data frame:

> ```
> V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15  
> 1   1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   1   1   1   1   1   1  
> 2   1  1  1  1  1  1  1 -1 -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  
> 3   1  1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1  1   1   1  -1  -1  -1  -1 
> 4   1  1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  -1  -1   1   1   1   1  
> 5   1 -1 -1  1  1 -1 -1  1  1  -1  -1   1   1  -1  -1  
> 6   1 -1 -1  1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1   1   1  -1  -1   1   1  
> 7   1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1  1  -1  -1  -1  -1   1   1  
> 8   1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1  1 -1 -1   1   1   1   1  -1  -1  
> 9  -1  1 -1  1 -1  1 -1  1 -1   1  -1   1  -1   1  -1  
> 10 -1  1 -1  1 -1  1 -1 -1  1  -1   1  -1   1  -1   1  
> 11 -1  1 -1 -1  1 -1  1  1 -1   1  -1  -1   1  -1   1  
> 12 -1  1 -1 -1  1 -1  1 -1  1  -1   1   1  -1   1  -1  
> 13 -1 -1  1  1 -1 -1  1  1 -1  -1   1   1  -1  -1   1 
> 14 -1 -1  1  1 -1 -1  1 -1  1   1  -1  -1   1   1  -1  
> 15 -1 -1  1 -1  1  1 -1  1 -1  -1   1  -1   1   1  -1  
> 16 -1 -1  1 -1  1  1 -1 -1  1   1  -1   1  -1  -1   1
> ```

First, I use `combn(4:15, 3)` to calculate the combination.

Like this:

> ```
>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] ....      [,220] 
> [1,]    4    4    4    4    4    4    4    4    4     4     4     4     4 ....         13 
> [2,]    5    5    5    5    5    5    5    5    5     5     6     6     6 ....         14  
> [3,]    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14    15     7     8     9 ....         15
> ```

My problem is: How to use the result of `combn(4:15, 3)` and my data set to get a lot of matrix? (in this case, I need 220 matrices because there are 220 combinations.)

Take the first combination for example,
The first combination is:

```
       [,1]   
[1,]    4      
[2,]    5      
[3,]    6
```

So I　take column 4, column 5 and column 6 from my data frame to get a new matrix like this:

```
 V4 V5 V6 
1  1  1  1 
2  1  1  1   
3  1 -1 -1 
4  1 -1 -1  
5  -1  1  1 
6  -1  1  1 
7  -1 -1 -1 
8  -1 -1 -1 
9  -1  1 -1 
10 -1  1 -1  
11 -1 -1  1 
12 -1 -1  1 
13  1  1 -1 
14  1  1 -1 
15  1 -1  1  
16  1 -1  1
```

Does anyone have some simple pieces of code to do this?  Thanks for everybody's help!

Comment: Just to clarify, do you want to fetch all the 220 `data.frame` subsets and store in a variable (like Ananda's solution)? Or do you not know how to index and you require *not* to load all `data.frame` subsets at the same time?

Comment: @Arun +1, it is important to know this.

Comment: @Arun
I'm not sure which method is better for what I want to achieve in the next step.

In the next step, I want to add a fixed column to each of the 220 subsets creating a new set of subsets (set A). And then I want to multiply the columns in each subset (of set A) using the pattern of combn(4,2), then combn(4,3), then combn(4,4). And then to create a another set of subset (set B) with the results, including the original 4 columns.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`combn` has a function argument, so you can simply do:

```
output <- combn(4:15, 3, FUN = function(x) mydf[x], simplify = FALSE)
```

This generates a `list` of `data.frame`s. Here's the first:

```
output[[1]]
#    V4 V5 V6
# 1   1  1  1
# 2   1  1  1
# 3  -1 -1 -1
# 4  -1 -1 -1
# 5   1  1 -1
# 6   1  1 -1
# 7  -1 -1  1
# 8  -1 -1  1
# 9   1 -1  1
# 10  1 -1  1
# 11 -1  1 -1
# 12 -1  1 -1
# 13  1 -1 -1
# 14  1 -1 -1
# 15 -1  1  1
# 16 -1  1  1
```

And the 220th:

```
output[[220]]
#    V13 V14 V15
# 1    1   1   1
# 2   -1  -1  -1
# 3   -1  -1  -1
# 4    1   1   1
# 5    1  -1  -1
# 6   -1   1   1
# 7   -1   1   1
# 8    1  -1  -1
# 9   -1   1  -1
# 10   1  -1   1
# 11   1  -1   1
# 12  -1   1  -1
# 13  -1  -1   1
# 14   1   1  -1
# 15   1   1  -1
# 16  -1  -1   1
```

---

For comparison, here's `combn` by itself:

```
> temp <- combn(4:15, 3)
> ncol(temp)
[1] 220
> temp[, 1]
[1] 4 5 6
> temp[, 220]
[1] 13 14 15
```

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there, just use each column as index for data frame.

```
df <- your.data.frame
idx <- combn(4:15, 3)

## first
df[idx[,1]]

## 19th
df[idx[,19]]
```

Comment: Not quite the way to recommend, I think.

Comment: I am curious to know the reason, I will modify/delete accordingly.

Comment: A loop is not quite obvious. I assume: to type 19 times `df[idx[,.]]`?? If so, it's ugly and unnecessary. But I'd not recommend a loop as well. Ananda's solution pretty much covers the best solution possible. In this case, I cant think of another "equivalent" solution.

Comment: I'm confused now, in the other solution one uses `output[[i]]` where as here one uses `df[idx[,i]]`.

Comment: In the other solution, he subsets *directly* from `combn`'s function argument and it gives a list of data.frames. Here, you propose to index 19 times with `idx[,.]` by yourself (typing 19 times)? At least that's what I get from your code. This means you're creating 19 variables?

Comment: Well `idx[,19]` returns `4  6 15`, so `df[idx[,19]]` returns `V4`,`V6` and `V15`

Comment: Tell me this, are you proposing to index every time to create the subset? (or) Create 19 variables, one for each subset? Which one are you suggesting?

Comment: I don't get your 2nd option. `19` was just an arbitrary example. There are `220` subsets possible. Ofcourse the subset can be stored the first time it is indexed.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28607/discussion-between-arun-and-e4e5f4)